# Is any tools can check my network card?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

My network no stable. Sometimes slower (ex. speed test result 10 ~ 30 Mbps) than normal, i try speed test, is really slower, page loading take time.
I try `Reset TCP/IP (Internet Protocol) and winsock`but it does not work.
Sometimes is normal (200 Mbps+). I see in `Resource Monitor`, no other app using.

Is any tools can check it?

Comment: Why do you think its your.network rather then ISP?

Comment: Welcome. This would have been better asked on our [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) sister-site if you want a tool.

Comment: @davidgo ping with no packet loss. I also have try speed test using my phone when **slow**, but phone result is normal.

Comment: If you know any possible hardware fault, how to check network card status, or something else, you can write down here.
If you got software suggest, direct to my [new question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/65622/57064)
I will delete it other side, if get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Wired ethernet?

Get a can of contact cleaner ($£€ 5 from Radio Shack or equivalent) - apply liberally *[with the power off]* to all contacts right through to the router.
Holding the locking clips down, push/pull each one 10 times or more whilst wet to aid the cleaning, then disconnect & allow to fully dry before reassembling & powering up.

It's something you should do every year or two anyway, & even if it's not the cause you then know it's not the cause.

Comment: I no thick that is rounter problem. Because when *slow*, I will using other device to check.
But I checking using my phone is 5.0GHz, my PC connect to 2.4GHz. Sometimes is happen after idle or sleep. cool starup normally no problem

Comment: Your comment appears to have identified the problem - if you are connecting via 2.4 gig WIFI the issue is likely interference from other sources (but Im not sure.how you get 200 mwgabit.on 802.11n!)